# How to retrieve the comments or at least the number of comments hidden on a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to retrieve the comments marked as spam/hidden or deleted by the admin of a page. 
I can't find a way to do that.

Please help!

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't know how I can improve my question...

Answer (score 0):

if its not in facebooks API documentation then I dont know what to tell you, you most likely cant do it. I would think that stuff that has been deleted is only accessible if your Zuckerburg.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using FQL. Try querying FQL comments table.